# mu4e with org-mode: LaTeX and R in emails

Tags: emacs, org-mode, mu

I'm trying to reproduce this awesome email from [this blog post](http://www.brool.com/index.php/using-mu4e) for the fun of it. Emacs, mu4e, org-mode Rich-text HTML email.

He sends an email from Emacs with mu4e, with LaTeX formulas and R plots, relying on org-mode to export the message to HTML and shell out rendering the images.

The org-mode HTML conversion works, if I have the cursor in the header and press `C-c C-c`, it converts the org format and sends a HTML message.

But when I try to include the LaTeX formulas, the rendered LaTeX .png fragments are removed before mu4e sends the email, and so aborts saying:

```
mm-insert-file-contents: Opening input file: no such file or directory, /tmp/ltxpng/...png
```

How can I delay removing the temporary files, until mu4e finishes sending the email?

Comment: My first impression is that mu4e uses the wrong png files. The command `org-create-formula-image` from `org-cdlatex` moves the temp-files to target files and then deletes the temp files. See e.g. `org-create-formula-image-with-dvipng`. At the end of this function you find `(copy-file pngfile tofile 'replace)`.

Comment: Hmm. I removed the last bit in `org-create-formula-image-with-dvipng` that cleans up the .png files, but it still aborts. I never see anything appearing in `/tmp/ltxpng/` either. I'm lost in which part of the the conversion is going wrong.

Comment: @Nyiti , @Tobias, I get something similar with `obipython` on `org-mu4e` see my [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/40661/17548) did you find a solution in regards to controlling where the PNG file is saved or read from?

Comment: In my case, `graph.png` ends up in my home directory.  If I explicitly specify `file: /tmp/graph.png` it ends up in the correct location, but I still get ```mm-insert-file-contents: Opening input file: No such file or directory, /tmp/file:/tmp/graph.png```...